# Do these circuits work the same way? (capacitors)

Tags: capacitor, pcb

[image: Two circuits]

I have a question about are this two circuits the same? I mean, will the capacitors act in the same way on both?
I'm asking this because I'm looking to the first picture and I think that the things that I connect will ignore the capacitor, is that right?

Comment: What is the capacitor being used for?

Comment: Above about 1 GHz there will be differences, crudely speaking, because every segment of wire is an antenna. But for most normal purposes, there's no difference between them.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Well, this circuit will power an atmega328 with a battery, but i don't know which one to use for a pcb. But, if you guys say it's the same then I should stick with the second since it's better for less space in pcb. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: So then decoupling? Will there be other devices on the power rails?

Comment: Right picture is alright.  Ceramic capacitor should be close to the microcontroller.  The location of the bulk electrolytic capacitor is less constrained.  Anywhere within, say 30mm to 50mm would be close enough.

Comment: @NickAlexeev The distance is not a problem, they will be close

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The 3.3v battery will be connected to the capacitor and then it will be connected to the atmega328. there will be no other things connected directly (except a resistor)

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no.

It depends on the frequency components of the current/voltage in the circuit.

The additional traces behave like (low-value) resistors for low frequencies, like inductors for high frequencies, like antennas for very high frequencies, and like waveguides for even higher frequencies.

So for high currents, the resistance may be a problem because of voltage drop.  For high frequencies, the inductance may be a problem because it works against the desired effects of the capacitance.  For the antenna problem, the loop area is important, so in this example the left circuit would have a bigger loop area and thus couple/radiate more.  Whether that is a problem, however, is entirely application-dependent.

For low-current, near-DC, there is virtually no difference.

If used for power supply decoupling, as I interpret it here, it is worth to note that the "aggressivenes"(steepness) of any supply current spikes (from microcontrollers etc.) is more important than the operating frequency of the component.

Rule of thumb: big high-value capacitors are used to decouple high-energy low-frequency content (thus placement is not as critical), while small low-value capacitors decouple low-energy high-frequency content and are placed near the consumer.